# Regex expression for line length limiting

Tags: regex, regex-group

I want regex expression where the minimum and maximum characters allowed can be from 1 to 100 but each line should accept only 10 characters and not more than that.

If I type 100 characters it can take to how many lines ever it want but each line not exceeding 10 characters.

I am able to frame for total characters but not matching the requirement of only 10 characters per line.

What I have is:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]){1,100}$
```

Requirement is I can give n number of lines but in total the characters shouldn't exceed 100 as well as the characters in a single line shouldn't exceed 10.

Comment: You need to specify the tool/lang you're using, else it's just guessing. Further in your max 100 characters, are line-breaks included (max 100 "empty" lines)? What about `\r\n` count as two (max 50 crlf empty lines)? ...

Comment: Java language and no empty lines

Comment: How about something like [`\A(?![\s\S]{101})(?:[\w-]{1,10}$\r?\n?)+\Z`](https://regex101.com/r/6ElT66/1) (does not allow empty lines besides at the end of the string, 100 chars allowed in total including crlf)

Comment: /^([^\n]{0,10})*$/ Use this and simply test the string length separately

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what line ending encoding you're using, you could do something like this:

```
^(([a-zA-Z0-9_-]){1,10}){1,10}$
```

make sure to use multiline matching though